# How do I do an integer list intersection while keeping duplicates?

Tags: c#, duplicates, intersection

I'm working on a Greatest Common Factor and Least Common Multiple assignment and I have to list the common factors. Intersection() won't work because that removes duplicates. Contains() won't work because if it sees the int in the second list it returns all matching ints from the first list. Is there a way to do an Intersection that is not Distinct?

edit: sorry for not providing an example, here is what I meant:

if I have the sets:

```
{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}
```

I would want the output

```
{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4}
```

Comment: If a is { 3,3,3,3 } and b is  { 3,3 }, how many 3s do you expect in the output? 2, 4 or 6?

Comment: I think the answers below confuse the question.  The correct question is 'Find the intersection of two sets'.  The problem is that the `Intersect` operator removes duplicates - solve the problem without removing duplicates.

Comment: Why? That removes duplicates. Explain your logic.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan of course it does not remove duplicates two 3s directly coming from the intersection operation there is absolutely no removing duplicates going on!

Comment: or you may want to refer to the basic definition of set intersection operation.

Comment: A set cannot have duplicate values (either mathematically or in c#), so what you have there are not sets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ILookup<int, int> lookup1 = list1.ToLookup(i => i);
ILookup<int, int> lookup2 = list2.ToLookup(i => i);

int[] result =
(
  from group1 in lookup1
  let group2 = lookup2[group1.Key]
  where group2.Any()
  let smallerGroup = group1.Count() < group2.Count() ? group1 : group2
  from i in smallerGroup
  select i
).ToArray();
```

The where expression is technically optional, I feel it makes the intent clearer.

---

If you want more terse code:

```
ILookup<int, int> lookup2 = list2.ToLookup(i => i);

int[] result =
(
  from group1 in list1.GroupBy(i => i)
  let group2 = lookup2[group1.Key]
  from i in (group1.Count() < group2.Count() ? group1 : group2)
  select i
).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 I am reminded heavily of this question, which we both answered. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460940/mastermind-scoring-algorithm-in-c-using-linq

Comment: @DuckReconMajor, my answer avoids fully counting both matching groups, this has to be better, however it is three years late :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/21776543/659190

Answer (score 11):

I wrote this extension to solve the problem:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Supersect<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, ICollection<T> b)
              => a.Where(b.Remove);
```

example:

```
var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 };
var b = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4};

var result = a.Supersect(b);
```

result:

```
{ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4 }
```

Comment: I like this, but it does mutate b by emptying it

Answer (score 4):

You could use this generic extension I wrote for [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21751976/659190), it is essentially a single Linq statement. Note that it uses `Zip` to avoid the needless full enumeration of matched groups.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Commom<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEnumerable<T> sequence,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (sequence == null)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }

    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    return source.GroupBy(t => t, comparer)
        .Join(
            sequence.GroupBy(t => t, comparer),
            g => g.Key,
            g => g.Key,
            (lg, rg) => lg.Zip(rg, (l, r) => l),
            comparer)
        .SelectMany(g => g);
}
```

this enables,

```
new[] {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}.Common(
    new[] {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}).ToArray()
```

maintaining the order of the source sequence, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? It should be pretty-much *O(n+m)*, where *n* is the number of items in `first` and *m* is the number of items in `second`.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Overlap<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first,
    IEnumerable<T> second, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    // argument checking, optimisations etc removed for brevity

    var dict = new Dictionary<T, int>(comparer);

    foreach (T item in second)
    {
        int hits;
        dict.TryGetValue(item, out hits);
        dict[item] = hits + 1;
    }

    foreach (T item in first)
    {
        int hits;
        dict.TryGetValue(item, out hits);
        if (hits > 0)
        {
            yield return item;
            dict[item] = hits - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Find the intersection of the two lists.
- Group the lists by the intersecting items
- Join the groups, and select the Min(Count) for each item
- Flatten into a new list.

See below:

```
var intersect = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
var groups1 = list1.Where(e => intersect.Contains(e)).GroupBy(e => e);
var groups2 = list2.Where(e => intersect.Contains(e)).GroupBy(e => e);

var allGroups = groups1.Concat(groups2);

return allGroups.GroupBy(e => e.Key)
    .SelectMany(group => group
        .First(g => g.Count() == group.Min(g1 => g1.Count())))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. To be fair, it is very similar to David B's answer except that it uses a join to do the association.

```
IEnumerable<Foo> seqA = ...
IEnumerable<Foo> seqB = ...

var result = from aGroup in seqA.GroupBy(x => x)
             join bGroup in seqB.GroupBy(x => x) 
                         on aGroup.Key equals bGroup.Key
             let smallerGroup = aGroup.Count() < bGroup.Count() 
                                ? aGroup : bGroup
             from item in smallerGroup
             select item;
```