# How use contains with two dimenzional list

Tags: c#

How find if any list in list of list contains all elements in another list?
Something like list list .contains(list), where list(list) is `stanjaDKA`, and list is `tmpzaNormalanPrijelaz`, and all list members are of type int?
I tried this but I get to much states in `stanjaDKA` at the end.

```
int indeks=stanjaDKA.FindIndex(x=>x.Equals(tmpzaNormalanPrijelaz));
if (indeks==-1 && tmpzaNormalanPrijelaz.Count>0)
{
    stanjaDKA.Add(tmpzaNormalanPrijelaz);
}
```

Comment: Reread your question like you knew nothing about your problem and see what information is missing for you to answer this question and update your question. Also, keep in mind that most of us can't understand your first language so rename your variables in English, please.

Answer (score 1):

> How find if any X in list of X

Use LINQ's `Any`:

```
bool anyXInListOfX = myListOfX(x => someConditionOnX);
```

---

> list contains all elements in another list

If you're not concerned about duplicate elements (i.e. if you're happy that `{1}` contains all the elements in `{1, 1}`), you can use LINQ's `Except` and check there is nothing left:

```
bool firstListContainsAllElementsInSecondList =
    !mySecondList.Except(myFirstList).Any();
```

---

However, *"any list contains all elements"* is equivalent to *"all lists* don't *contain all elements"*, and the `don't` cancels with the `!` in the above, so in your case I'd do something like

```
if (stanjaDKA.All(l => tmpzaNormalanPrijelaz.Except(l).Any()))
{
    stanjaDKA.Add(tmpzaNormalanPrijelaz);
}
```

This reads as *"if* all *the lists in `stanjaDKA` are each missing* at least one *element in `tmpzaNormalanPrijelaz`, add `tmpzaNormalanPrijelaz` to `stanjaDKA`"*.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you are really want this will help you to do the mayor stuff

```
        // Sample List<List<int>>
        var listList = new List<List<int>>();
        listList.Add(new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        listList.Add(new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        listList.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        listList.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 });
        listList.Add(new List<int>() { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });

        // the List you are seaching for
        var searchList = new List<int>() { 10 };

        foreach(List<int> list in listList)
        {
            var newList =list.Intersect(searchList);
            if (newList.Count() == searchList.Count)
            {
                string elements = "";
                foreach (int item in newList)
                {
                    elements += item + " ";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(elements);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

you should also take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011948/how-do-i-do-an-integer-list-intersection-while-keeping-duplicates) maybe you need it