# Check if HUGE dictionary contains a string and get all elemets that match element

Tags: c#, linq

I have two **huge dictionaries**, one named DictHashesSource with 2256001 lines and another dictionary named  DictHashesTarget with 2061735 lines.

```
Dictionary<int, string> DictHashesSource = new Dictionary<int, string>();
Dictionary<int, string> DictHashesTarget = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

What I want to do is, for each element of DictHashesSource  retrieve all elements in DictHashesTarget that match, and do the exact same thing in the oposite way.
To do so, I used LINQ like bellow:

```
IEnumerable<string> interceptedRowsSource = DictHashesSource.Values.Where(x => DictHashesTarget.Values.Contains(x)).ToList();
IEnumerable<string> interceptedRowsTarget = DictHashesTarget.Values.Where(x => DictHashesSource.Values.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

The problem is, as the two dictionaries are really big, it takes more than 1 hour to do each operation, is there any way to reduce the complexity of this algorithm?

**Note:** I really have to use two dictionaries because I will have to use the keys in further operations.

**Another note:** The same value doesnt have the same key in both dictionaries

Comment: More info please. What is DictHashesSource defined as? What is DictHashesTarget defined as? Do you need to materialize it (.ToList()) before other operations?

Comment: Every time you call `Values` its O(1) time complexity, so each statement you have with the `Contains` is O(n2*2)

Comment: `dict1.Values.Intersect(dict2.Values);`?

Comment: `Dictionary.Values` is effectively just a linear list and not even a simple one at that, since it has to walk the buckets. Create new collections with the values (like `HashSet`) and search in those. (`Enumerable.Intersect`, `.Union` and `.Except` use `Set` in the background.)

Comment: dict1.Values.Intersect(dict2.Values); doesnt work because it doesnt retrieve the duplicates

Comment: Dictionary will not work for this, you need to have a tree type search like this: https://github.com/gmamaladze/trienet

Comment: For duplicates, you can reduce the values to tuples with a value and an occurrence count, or use `Enumerable.ToLookup`.

Comment: @Pugnatore Check [this `Overlap()` extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5012081/8967612). You can do `dict1.Values.Overlap(dict2.Values).ToList();`. Should be pretty quick.

Comment: how are the dictionaries populated?

Comment: Please provides samples/explain what the `int` and `string` values are. Seems like this may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be to make an reverse dictionary. So you have more constant results. So you'r values becomes keys and vice versa.

```
        Dictionary<int, string> source = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Dictionary<int, string> target = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        source.Add(1, "a");
        source.Add(2, "b");
        source.Add(3, "c");

        target.Add(4, "c");
        target.Add(5, "d");
        target.Add(6, "e");

        // Reverse index:
        var reverseSource = source.Reverse();
        var reverseTarget = target.Reverse();

        foreach (var sourceItem in reverseSource)
        {
            if (reverseTarget.ContainsKey(sourceItem.Key)){
                Console.WriteLine($"Source and Target contains {sourceItem.Key}");
            }
        }
```

With the following reverse dictionary function.

```
    public static Dictionary<TValue, TKey> Reverse<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<TValue, TKey>();
        foreach (var entry in source)
        {
            if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(entry.Value))
                dictionary.Add(entry.Value, entry.Key);
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
```

You could add all the keys as a comma seperated list if it is needed?

Comment: yes it makes sense, but it is still taking more than one hour to do this comparison

Comment: I will add code snippet to help :) You still need to make 1 run through. For that data it shouldn't take a long time. 2sek

Comment: This is quadratic. There's no need for it to be quadratic: you can make it linear.

Comment: Redid the entire approach to use reverse dictionaries instead.

Comment: how does this make it better?

Answer (score 0):

You could create HashSets with values from both dictionaries.

```
HashSet<string> HashesSourceSet;

HashSet<string> HashesTargetSet;
```

Then do something like this:

```
var result1 = HashesSourceSet.Where(x => HashesTargetSet.Contains(x)).ToList();
var result2 = HashesTargetSet.Where(x => HashesSourceSet.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

This would reduce the complexity to O(n)

----------------- UPDATE --------------------

As you mentioned that you needed count of hashes, you could do as below:

```
Dictionary<string, int> HashesWithCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var x in DictHashesSource.Values)
{   
    HashesWithCount[x] = HashesWithCount.ContainsKey(x) ? (HashesWithCount [x] + 1) : 1;
}
```

Now you have the count of duplicate values.

Comment: The problem is that I have some duplicated values, and as far as I know HashSet doesnt allow duplicated values right?

Comment: Yea, hashset will keep distinct values only. If you need their count, you could create a Dictionary<string, int> with your hash values and count of them.While adding hashes to the dictionary, if the key is already present then increment the value.